# Android Handler.createAsync().How does it work?

Tags: android, android-handler

The doc says it will "Create a new Handler whose posted messages and runnables are not subject to synchronization barriers such as display vsync."

What does this mean? When should I use createAsync()?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that this is a Handler that doesn't wait for the display VSYNC signal, thus it's more responsive but resource-consuming. Should be used in performance critical display code.